# How to post data from C# to an ajax website?

Tags: c#, ajax, webrequest

I work in C# and so far I used WebRequest method to GET and POST data. I use Fiddler to check what is the browser doing and I got to a point where the data is retrieved from Ajax after posting some data. 
I am not sure if I have to add to my project a javascript page or what and what code do I need in the javascript file and how to call it.
In essence, I have to post the data {"name":"ABCD"} to url www.example.com/Website.AJAX,Website.ashx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is not so different from ordinary request, so you can just post it as usual. Most likely problem is how the backend treat that it is an ajax request (if it does at all).

As it looks like you are using the WebForms there on backend, you just need to add a special header most likely (`X-Requested-With`). Some frameworks add it, though it's not a real requirement of the ajax request.

All in all I would just post an ordinary request with `WebRequest` as you did before. If that does not work, you need to study the original request from web UI to see what is different. E.g. a special header or request `Content-Type` is JSON or something like that.

P.S. If you use JSON in the body it's better to explicitly set content type to `application/json; charset=utf-8` unless there is something special with the server.

Comment: Does this mean I don't need to use javascript? On a normal GET or POST, I can see the elements of the form in Fiddler, but when I get to Ajax, the form is not visible anymore.

Comment: You don't need javascript. There is nothing special javascript can do that you cannot do in C# (unless WebRequest has some special limitations). The reason you cannot see the WebForms in there is because you don't post in that format. You use JSON instead. There is a JSON tab in fiddler that will show you this data.

Comment: I think web forms tab in there is for `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Thanks for help. You were right, I was able to post the data from C# and read the result. And indeed, the JSON tab was showing the posted data.